# A BdMO 2021 Question

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, coordinate-systems

> Two toads named Gamakichi and Gamatatsu are sitting at the points $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ respectively. Their goal is to reach $(5,5)$ and $(7,5)$ respectively by making one unit jumps in positive $x$ or $y$ direction at a time. How many ways can they do this while ensuring that there is no point on the plane where both Gamakichi And Gamatatsu land on?

It's a problem from *BdMO 2021*. I have no idea about how to approach this kind of problems (Cause I'm a beginner). Please help me solve it. And sorry if it's too easy.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Suppose he is unable to approach the problem, he can't really explain the working can he? Seems like a fine question to me

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why I'm being downvoted. I'm new here and I get demotivated to ask questions here for being downvoted.

Comment: I am not a downvoter but I can understand why the downvotes. Even when you have not found an approach to solve the problem, you would still have some thoughts on the problem if you have attempted it yourself. It is not correct to say that you have no idea _at all_. Even if you take a piece of paper and pencil and draw some possible paths for them, you get some idea about what paths work and what do not. The site requires you to provide additional context and wants to see that you have made a sincere attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: What is the BdMO? Bangladesh?

Comment: Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad @ParclyTaxel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without restrictions the answer would be $\binom{10}5^2=63504$. Now for any invalid pair of paths taken by the two toads, swapping the parts of their trajectories after their first meeting gives a pair of paths where Gamakichi goes to $(7,5)$ and Gamatatsu to $(5,5)$.

[image]

Gamatatsu's new path must separate $(0,0)$ from $(7,5)$, so the toads' trajectories under this modified scheme must always cross; the transformation described above can thus always be undone, yielding a bijection between invalid path pairs and path pairs under the modified scheme. The cardinality of the second set is $\binom{12}5\binom85=44352$, so the answer is $63504-44352=19152$.